# How to polish Corian countertop?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters

I have a Corian countertop that has seen many years of wear and tear.  I'd like to sand and polish it however the instructions that came with the countertop recommend Hope's Countertop Polish as the final step.

My challenge is that it appears that the Hope's products are not available for sale in Canada.  I have checked with all the major home improvement stores around me and it seems that nobody has ever heard of anything for polishing Corian.  Everything they have is either for granite or 'natural stone' only which I don't think will work on a Corian countertop.

Is there something else I can use to polish my countertop?  Ideally something that's available in Canada would be excellent.

Comment: We can do a trade if you'd like.  I'll send you a bottle of polish and you send me a bag of ketchup chips.  I miss Canada.

Comment: Why not order it from Amazon or other online retailer? [Hope's Countertop Polish on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Hopes-Countertop-Polish-8-Ounces/dp/B0007NP5EG).

Comment: @Tester101 - Seems the online retailers I've looked at don't ship to Canada...  The Amazon.ca site is severely limited in selection for almost anything.

Comment: @pilotcam - Are you serious?  I'd consider a trade.

Answer (score 2):

If you're really going to sand it you don't need a polishing compound to finish.  I worked a deep scratch out of a small section using a quarter-sheet power sander, and then worked up through 800, 1000, 1500, 2000, and 2500 grit paper, at which point it had a mirror finish.

(Only problem is it now looks so much better than the other Corian sections, and it would take a full day to repeat the process on the whole surface area.)

Answer (score 0):

I have used polishing and rubbing compounds to polish and remove scratches from our Corian countertop. A polishing machine definitely saves the elbows. Clear epoxy may be used to fill deep scratches, though it will yellow with time.

Answer (score 0):

solid surface is typically available in matte, semigloss, and gloss finishes. If your countertops were glossy originally, all you should have to do is clean the surface with soapy water, an ammonia-based window cleaner, soft-scrub. Avoid cleaner like formula 409 or fantastik, which leave behind residues.

Comment: This does not address the question. He does not need to clean it, he heeds to refinish the surface.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you hire a professional, but if you really want to do it correctly you will need a random orbital sander. The best finish is 3m micron paper for Corian. The Home Depot stuff will clogg up in no time. The best practice is to clean thoroughly before sanding. All edges should be done by hand with sandpaper and steel wool. Never sand the top surface area by hand. You create swirl marks and will have an uneven finish. Rough areas=120 grit, all areas=220 grit, last step=320. That should provide a satin finish. Autobody sandpaper works well too. Sand in circular motion up and down the entire length and then left to right the entire length of the countertop.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum final grit should be 2500, better yet is 3,000 which gives a mirror finish.  4,000 for those who want to shave in the reflection.  Just keep in mind that if you start then you will need to do the entire top.  Otherwise you will have a section with a higher gloss than the rest. I am a bit ocd so I go up to 4,000 although my wife does not see a difference between that and 3,000.

I tried the polish rather than sanding discs to finish but while it works ok, it does not last at all.  Best is to start with and follow through with sanding discs-I prefer wet and dry because you can avoid a lot of dust all over everything that way

Comment: This is a better answer with the attempt at insulting another user. If you want to address someone else, earn 50 rep, then write a comment on the specific question/answer, don't try to address others in an answer.